# Trying to identify bandsaw

Tags: woodworking, bandsaw

I recently came into possession of this bandsaw. The brand is Builders and model, serial number, and manufacture year on shown in the images (click to enlarge). I can't find anything online regarding this brand. Any help is appreciated.

[image: General picture]
[image: Information Card]

Comment: 14 inch Taiwan made is likely a copy of a Delta 14. Sometimes they are so close parts will swap, sometimes they "copied" by using castings of the saw they were copying as molds so all the parts are off by the amount of shrinkage not allowed for in that method.

Comment: I found a "JWBS-14" made by JET, but can't tell from the pictures whether it's similar or not.

Comment: What difference would it make if you located the manufacturer?

Comment: @Jasen  Might be nice to know for parts/manuals/blades/accessories.

Comment: I would bet that taking a broken or "want to be upgraded" part to a wood workers store or good lumber yard, someone will be able to identify what the part is from and find an equivalent that will fit. Sometimes, shopping in person instead of online is worth it...

Comment: What's the question? Please revise to be more clear.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about home improvement.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is a **generic tool copied from the Delta/Rockwell 14" bandsaws** as Ecnerwal mentioned in a comment. It appears that similar/identical Taiwan-made saws were sold under the brand names [IMS](https://grassrootsmotorsports.com/forum/grm/ims-bandsaw/179808/page1/) ([and another](https://www.lumberjocks.com/topics/311719)); [King Feng Fu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4l1U.jpg); [Foremost Machinery](https://sawmillcreek.org/showthread.php?91350-14-quot-Taiwan-Bandsaw-Part-Needed); [and others](https://sawmillcreek.org/showthread.php?181559-Reliant-14-quot-Bandsaw&p=1872706#post1872706), including Builders it would seem!

[Highland Woodworking offers these rollers](https://www.highlandwoodworking.com/bandrollersfor14taiwansaws.aspx) for "Taiwan Saws" which supports "**Taiwanese 14 inch bandsaw**" as a species of tool.

Reading over these linked threads, it seems "Taiwan Bandsaws" often use 92½"-long blades, which are harder to find in retail stores than 93½"-long blades, but which [can be found online](https://www.olsonsaw.net/shop/band-saw-blades/flex-back-band-saw-blades/92-1-2in-long/). Also seems replacement parts marked for Delta or Rockwell 14" saws may or may not fit, depending on your particular specimen of saw.